# How to create a condition with an Integer being NULL?

Tags: c#, datatable, null, integer

I am adding a row to a DataTable t with a column of type INTEGER. According to a condition, the column must be null in some cases. How do I do that?

```
t.Rows.Add(new Object[] { String, Integer) })
```

I can't assign Null or DBNull.Value to an Integer, BUT I actually can assign DBNull.Value to the second parameter of the t.Rows.Add Command.
So, how do I do it? By intuition I would do this (which of course is not allowed)

```
int Integer = NULL;
if(t.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   Integer = Convert.ToInt32(t.Rows[0][1]);
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [nullable types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types), or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Please don't use the names of types for variable names; it makes it quite confusing to read and understand what is going on...

Comment: Heretic Monkey, you might be right, although the intention was to simplify

Comment: David, thanks. I had heard of nullable types but only now I know how the can make things easier. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

For many years now, .NET has supported nullable value types. In this case, you can do something like this:

```cs
int? number = myDataRow.IsDBNull(columnIndex) ? (int?) null : myDataRow.Field<int>(columnIndex));
```

I'm not at my computer right now so I'll double check that ternary statement but it should be pretty close.

You then have to treat that variable as nullable, using its `HasValue` and `Value` properties.